# The Anthropic principle as a physical embodiment of the Axiom of Choice

Tags: reality, axiom

This question pertains to physical reality, but it would be deemed inappropriate in [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) because of its speculative, metaphysical nature. It also touches on the subject of singling out elements in uncountable sets, which in Mathematics it is typically considered not a logically derivable property of Set theory proper, but something that needs the formal addition of the so-called [Axiom of Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice).

The Anthropic principle is closely related to [Modal Realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_realism), which can be interpreted as a "Copernican principle" for universes: The logical principles and rules that the current reality abides to, has nothing special among all other logical possibilities, beyond satisfying the self-consistent requirements that would allow "adequate" internal perception and cognition*.

But beyond "gut feelings" Is not entirely clear to me if there is a way to philosophically define what differences should one expect, if said set of logical possibilities were: either extremely large but finite, infinite but countable, or wildly uncountable. This last one seems to be the most popular among physicists, while theological narratives tend (at least on a superficial interpretation) to hint on the first.

The Axiom of choice seems to be a required addendum to any infinite (countable or uncountable) metaphysics, as simple probability measures cannot explain visible ontology.

Since it seems clear that the universe is perceivable by us, if the Axiom of choice was a simple "mathematician's trick" with no ultimate platonic reality, then reality would imply that the set of logical possibilities for reality is finite.

Is this a valid conclusion? Is a consistent assertion to claim that the Axiom of choice being false (in an absolute form) would imply a finite set of realities, while only a true (again, in absolute form) Choice principle (no need to prefix with "axiom" anymore) would enable "mathematically miraculous" experiences like ours of singled out elements among infinite realities?

*: For certain underspecified but "adequate" definition of adequacy

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reasoning behind your statement *The Axiom of choice seems to be a required addendum to any infinite (countable or uncountable) metaphysics, as simple probability measures cannot explain visible ontology*? In particular, suppose only a countably infinite set of computable universes exist as in Tegmark's proposal, why do you think we can't define a probability distribution on this set without the axiom of choice?

Comment: @Hypnosifl I guess technically you could, but it would impose additional requirements to assure probabilities remaining normalizable, like vanishing on infinite subsets. But that was my initial take in any case on the problem

Comment: @Hypnosifl An appealing alternative is that you do away logically with the notion of normalizable probabilities. there is nothing like absolute measures for individual possibilities, but relative measures *between* possibilities, akin to what Metropolis-Hastings algorithm does. But then we must add elements to the metaphysics that involves transitions or relationships between ontologies

Comment: " singling out elements in uncountable sets" does not require choice. I did not get the impression that you have an accurate understanding of the axiom of choice. Also what does "simple probability measures cannot explain visible ontology" mean? Third, set theory is not reality, why do you reify set theory like this? Set theory is a formal symbolic system, not unlike chess. You wouldn't ask if the way the knight moves implies limitations on how photons travel.

Comment: Does the Anthropic Principle really require such a large number of choices? Why not numbers as small as thousands, hundreds or even less?

Comment: @user4894 I don't understand your statement. If the possibilities are on equal footing, are infinite, and there is no algorithm to iterate through the elements, I don't know how you can avoid (requiring) choice

Comment: @D.Halsey We know that zero is impossible, anything between 1 and any finite number would be the most consistent with a probabilistic interpretation of the principle. That would be the simplest explanation that doesn't require any "embodiment" of the axiom of choice

Comment: @lurscher You don't seem to know what the axiom of choice says. You can always choose an element from an infinite set, with or without choice. Choice only comes up when you want to make infinitely many simultaneous choices from infinitely many nonempty sets. I think you're confusing choice with the fact that there's no uniform probability measure on a countably infinite set.